# OpenSSH < 7.0 Multiple vulnerabilities question

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, vulnerability, cve, openssh

Nessus reports this as Critical however there are issues such as 'CVE-2015-5600' that CVE is 8.5 but Red Hat reports it as a 'Low' issue. https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2015-5600 Reports it as 'Low' Impact. More over I dont understand why Red Hat says that is not affected from most of the OpenSSH vulnerabilities - any explanation ? For example --> https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2016-1907 this doesnt affect Red Hat products... What are they doing differently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### CVE-2015-5600: MaxAuthTries limit bypass via duplicates in KbdInteractiveDevices

This vulnerability has low impact on RHEL, because by default the option `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` is disabled in default configuration. Though it is or will be fixed in RHEL 6 and 7.

### CVE-2016-1907: openssh: out-of-bounds read in packet handling code

This one does not affect RHEL systems, because the bug was introduced in `openssh-6.8` (RHEL 7 ships `openssh-6.6.1p1`) as [comment to the related bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1298746#c1).

Also other vulnerabilities can be similarly explained (usually because the the bug was introduced recently). Openssh is quite secure and breaking through all the levels of security needs a lot of effort.

<sub>*Disclaimer: I work for Red Hat.*</sub>